# Initializing DropDown list from a table

Tags: visual-studio-2010, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.0

I'm new to `MVC4` programming. Followed the `NerdDinner` tutorial initially. Now am gradually complicating the scenarios. I want to populate a `DropDown` list from a table's field but don't know how to, although I searched for relevant material from Internet but couldn't get some sophisticated info.

The scenario is that there are 2 tables `Software` and `Category` (which represents the category of the software whether it is Anti-Virus, Graphics etc...).

1. In `Software` table, `catID` is in `int` form which has a foreign key relationship with the `catID` in `Category` table.
2. In `Category` table, `catID` and `catTitle` are the only fields.

Now while creating the `Create` view to add/upload a new `Software`, I want that the `catTitle` of all the `catID`s are shown in a `Drop-Down List`, from which the user will choose the Software category, but I don't know how to do that....

The model being used in my `Create.cshtml` file is

```
@model SoftwarePortal.Models.Software
```

So in this case, what will be the arguments for

```
@Html.DropDownListFor()
```

How and where should i specify the SQL stmt to fetch `catIDs` and corresponding `catTitles`? (I am using Linq to SQL...)

How to access a table that is not declared as the model of the current View...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller
suppose your Generated database entity will be SoftDBEntities

```
private SoftDBEntities se = new SoftDBEntities();
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //se.Categorys will get all categories
    //se.Categorys may be replace with a function which return records from Category table
    ViewBag.CatId= new SelectList(se.Categorys, "CatId", "CatTitle");
    return View();
}
```

In cshtml file

```
@Html.DropDownList("CatId")
```

if above statement not work then try this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model.CatId,(SelectList)ViewBag.CatId,"CatId","CatTitle")
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh gosh! Would you believe all that I needed to do was to **typecast** the `ViewBag.Categories` to `SelectList` inside `@Html.DropDownListFor()`!!! Because it doesn't automatically take the shape of the stored item...

So stupid of me...